# Why would a merge successfully run but no results when checking?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I ran a merge query to update some totals on a table; it ran successfully, but when I go to look at the table, no data appears to have been set. What'd I do wrong?

My merge query originally had the update set values with s.total = t.total etc etc, but that gave me an error of:

```
The multi-part identifier "s.total_qty_received" could not be bound.
```

Merge query:

```
MERGE INTO dbo.PO_HEADER_TEST t
   USING (select po_header_id, sum(qty_ordered) as total_qty_ordered,
sum(qty_received) as total_qty_received,
sum(qty_cancelled) as total_qty_cancelled,
sum(qty_open) as total_qty_open,
sum(amt_ordered) as total_amt_ordered,
sum(amt_received) as total_amt_received,
sum(amt_open) as total_amt_open
from dbo.PO_DETAIL_TEST
GROUP BY po_header_id) as s
   ON (t.po_header_id = s.po_header_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET total_qty_received=t.total_qty_received, total_qty_cancelled=t.total_qty_cancelled, 
total_qty_open=t.total_qty_open, total_amt_ordered=t.total_amt_ordered, total_amt_received=t.total_amt_received, 
total_amt_open=t.total_amt_open;
```

Afterwards, I run a query to check that something had happened, but the query returns no values

```
select * from po_header_test where total_qty_ordered is not null
```

The subquery in my merge runs correctly, and it says query successfully ran, but no results occur?

I updated the query based on comments from below, but it still returns no changes to the PO Header table.

```
MERGE INTO dbo.PO_HEADER_TEST t
   USING (select po_header_id, sum(COALESCE( qty_ordered, 0)) as total_qty_ordered,
sum(COALESCE( qty_received, 0)) as total_qty_received,
sum(COALESCE( qty_cancelled, 0)) as total_qty_cancelled,
sum(COALESCE( qty_open, 0)) as total_qty_open,
sum(COALESCE( amt_ordered, 0)) as total_amt_ordered,
sum(COALESCE( amt_received, 0)) as total_amt_received,
sum(COALESCE( amt_open, 0)) as total_amt_open
from dbo.PO_DETAIL_TEST
GROUP BY PO_HEADER_ID) as s
   ON (t.po_header_id = s.po_header_id)
   WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET  total_qty_received=s.total_qty_received, total_qty_cancelled=s.total_qty_cancelled, 
total_qty_open=s.total_qty_open, total_amt_ordered=s.total_amt_ordered, total_amt_received=s.total_amt_received, 
total_amt_open=s.total_amt_open;
```

Comment: you are updating the target (dbo.PO_HEADER_TEST t) with its own values `SET total_qty_received=t.total_qty_received`

Comment: OK, but if I try to use s.total_qty_received = total_qty_received then it gives me the error I first mentioned, about multi-part identifier can't be bound

Comment: `s.total_qty_received = total_qty_received` :: update the source (which is not possible). It would be easier if you aliased the source columns differently, eg. sum(qty_ordered) as new_qty_ordered....

Comment: Let's start over. You are merging FROM s TO t. You can only update rows in t - and for the sake of future generations, use a short (but not 1 character) and descriptive alias for your tables - and WHITESPACE! It makes NO logical sense to attempt to update s because it is composed of aggregated rows - which row or rows would be updated? And would that action immediately make your data since it would change the values you summed in order to do that update? So - change `SET total_qty_received=t.total_qty_received` to `SET total_qty_received = s.total_qty_received`

Comment: Ok, so I rearranged it to be total_qty_received = s.total_qty_received, and it says 'code'Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.'code' which I don't quite get, because obviously the value I'm setting is null, that's why I'm setting it?

Comment: And if I set SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, it runs successfully...but no results in PO_HEADER_TEST table still.

Comment: The message "_Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation._" applies to the `sum()` operations in your source query. It happens because at least one row in `PO_DETAIL_TEST` has a null value in the columns you are summing up.

Comment: Ok, but how come nothing happens when I run it, even when I turn off ansi_warnings?